# When are you required to use a junction box extension to make it flush with the wall?

Tags: electrical, drywall

Say you have a junction box whose face is recessed significantly into the wall. For instance, if the face of the junction box is actually at the back of the drywall or perhaps 1/2" too deep.

Is it required to use a box extension in a case like this? Mechanically it would be possible just to use longer screws to attach the device - but would that violate code or cause some other problem?

(USA)

Comment: Going to add this because I didn't know about them for the longest time... for boxes that are not extremely recessed, you can get a [caterpillar](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Ideal-Spacers-25-Pack-172451L/202937111) to fill in the gap between the outlet and the recessed box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ARTICLE 314
>
> Outlet, Device, Pull, and Junction Boxes; Conduit Bodies; Fittings;
>   and Handhole Enclosures
>
> 314.20 In Wall or Ceiling. In walls or ceilings with a surface of concrete, tile, gypsum, plaster, or other noncombustible material,
>   boxes employing a ﬂush-type cover or faceplate shall be installed so
>   that the front edge of the box, plaster ring, extension ring, or
>   listed extender will not be set back of the ﬁnished surface more than
>   6 mm (1⁄4 in.). In walls and ceilings constructed of wood or other
>   combustible surface material, boxes, plaster rings, extension rings,
>   or listed extenders shall be ﬂush with the ﬁnished surface or project
>   therefrom.