# Installed new switches - ground wire connection touches wood?

Tags: wiring, walls, dimmer-switch, junction-box

I ended up swapping out all three switches in my box.  The two new dimmer switches are not the same design as the old and these have the ground wire woven through holes in the metal base. (See photo) Concerned that this base and wire contacts the wood tongue and groove.

The old switches had all wires running into the back, so even though the metal base was screwed into the box and the wood was sandwiched between the metal and the box - there were no wires or connections actually touching it.  Which made me a little concerned, but figuring it had already been that way for 20 years...

But now, not so sure. I wouldn't be concerned, but it's different and I err on the side of caution.  The box is not flush with the wall, and even if it were, the base of the switch would still overlap the wood. Is it a problem to have the wood sandwiched between the box and the mounts or should they be flush with the box?

Also - there is a pretty big difference between the depth from the wall to the box at the top and the bottom, too, so a simple extension isn't going to work.

Thanks in advance!  [image]

Answer (score 1):

The ground wires on your old switches were surely connected to the exposed metal parts of the switches, so it's really no different on that basis.

It is normal for the switch "ears" or extended parts (less ear-like on these as they don't have the scored parts you can break off for other types of boxes) bear on the wall surface. There is a figure for how close the switch box is supposed to be to the wall surface, <s>but it does not have to be absolutely flush,</s> and the "slop" is intended to be taken up this way so that the switches and trim ring end up flat to the wall, even though the box is not precisely aligned.

**Edit:** Per this question and answer [When are you required to use a junction box extension to make it flush with the wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/173136/18078)

The fact that the wall is wood (or otherwise combustible material) means that the box IS supposed to be completely flush with (or even protrude slightly from) the wall surface. *Otherwise* up to 1/4" setback is permitted.

Comment: But in general, it's okay to have the metal switch base overlap and be in direct contact with wood?  I suspected the ground wire might be connected to the metal in some way - but couldn't see it - and hate to assume.....guess I could have torn it apart.

Comment: Metal boxes are screwed/nailed onto wood studs everyday.  Switches/outlets are screwed onto metal boxes.  Ground wires are screwed to boxes and maybe switches/outlets.  Don't think it will make much difference(except code wise).

Comment: @Slhorn No, that situation is really bad, you need to get a 3-gang box extender and solve that "wood exposed in the box" problem.  This could turn arcing into a house fire.